# desktop sharing

Tags: windows, rdp, lync, lync-2010

I want to implement desktop sharing client with Lync as the server. Does Lync use RDP and if so can someone point me to an RDP implementation?

Can I tweak free RDP and make it work? Appreciate your inputs.

Comment: This doesn't seem like a programming question - it's probably better suited to SuperUser.com.  It'll likely be migrated automatically though, so hang tight and it'll work itself out... :-)

Comment: agree, unless you're talking about automating the Lync Desktop Sharing experience in code using one of the SDKs?

Comment: I have a lync desktop client on one side and an app on the other side. I want to use the app to connect to lync for desktop sharing. Can it be done? If so please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not have a Lync client on your other side, you will have a hard time getting application sharing to work. Using an RDP client will not work, since RDP is just a connection to a machine rather than a SIP call. The underlying protocol for the app sharing stream might be the same (I dont know about this), but you'll be missing the parts that deal with the whole Lync connection.

Michael Greenlee has written a bit on the subject of Application Sharing (which is used to share desktops) here: [Handling application sharing calls in UCMA](http://blog.greenl.ee/2012/02/06/handling-application-sharing-calls-ucma/), and an MSDN thread on the subject is here: [How to handle Application Sharing Invitation](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ucmanagedsdk/thread/c10fbde5-7193-4910-a249-89999bb5fc3b/), maybe this helps you?